# run the SyncAdapter in the background when the application is not running

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Is it possible to run the SyncAdapter in the background even when the application is not running? I want to update the sqlite database if there is any changes in the server , even when android application is not running?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best practice for this use-case is:

1) Fire a `Broadcast` from your server, whenever the data changes.

2) Start a service from the broadcast receiver. (you can send some extra data with your broadcast to distinguish between broadcast operations).

3) Update your database in your started service.

If the above solution is not an option, then:

I would recommend you to use [JobScheduler](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html) which is a newer and recommended approach for such use-cases.

Although, you can also achieve your goal using SyncAdapters. But nowadays, they are usually used when you need to maintain accounts or share AuthTokens between other apps or store some `SyncAdapter` specific data in your `ContentProviders`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run sync adapter periodically. It doesn't matter whether you app is running or not . It will always perform sync periodically.  Form the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html), you can add periodic sync like this way

```
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            ACCOUNT,
            AUTHORITY,
            Bundle.EMPTY,
            SYNC_INTERVAL);
```

And then in your **onPerformSync** method do you database stuff .

```
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account,Bundle extras,String authority,ContentProviderClient provider,SyncResult syncResult) {
    /*
     * Do your database stuff
     */
    ...
    }
```